# Linux: accessing PCIe status registers

Tags: linux, driver, pci-e

I need to count the number of PCIe correctable and uncorrectable errors detected in Linux.  How and where do I start?

- Is a Linux device driver an appropriate approach to count such errors?
- If a driver is appropriate, then what type of driver?  pcie driver? pseudo device driver?  extend existing driver that incurred the error?  I really don't know.
- I know PCIe has a device error/status register as part of the PCIe Capability structure; is there a way to listen on this register -- that is, is it possible to register a callback that is invoked when the register is updated?  if so, how?

Code/examples much appreciated.

THank you!

Comment: Is you ever find a solution to this?